# Oracle Regexp to split string based on first occurrence of delimiter

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split

I have the following data

```
1241 - ASGEF - AFZHE
1242 - ASGEF1
1243 - UJHAHAHG - AGHBNG
```

Expected output using oracle regexpr

```
ASGEF - AFZHE
ASGEF1
UJHAHAHG - AGHBNG
```

Answer (score 2):

`SUBSTR + INSTR` will probably run faster (i.e. no need for regular expressions). `result` shows that, while `result_2` shows one regexp option.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1241 - ASGEF - AFZHE'     from dual union all
  3     select '1242 - ASGEF1'            from dual union all
  4     select '1243 - UJHAHAHG - AGHBNG' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7         trim(substr(col, instr(col, '-') + 1)) result,
  8         ltrim(regexp_substr(col, '-.+'), '- ') result_2
  9  from test;

COL                      RESULT                   RESULT_2
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
1241 - ASGEF - AFZHE     ASGEF - AFZHE            ASGEF - AFZHE
1242 - ASGEF1            ASGEF1                   ASGEF1
1243 - UJHAHAHG - AGHBNG UJHAHAHG - AGHBNG        UJHAHAHG - AGHBNG

SQL>
```